# Combobox data wont update WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 2 pages (User and UserListing)
When I Add new user on **User Page** then change page to **UserListing Page** the ComboBoxUser on **UserListing Page** wont update automatically. Any Idea to solve this ?

this is my code
User.cs

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _firstName;
    public string FirstName {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { 
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    string _lastName;
    public string LastName {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { 
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }

    int _gender;
    public int Gender {
        get { return _gender; }
        set { 
            _gender = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Gender");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

UserListingViewModel.cs

```
public class UserListingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserListingViewModel()
    {
        LoadDataUser();
    }

    public void LoadDataUser()
    {
        ComboUserData = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
            "dLondre.Properties.Settings.CSLONDRE"].ConnectionString);

        string str = "";
        str += "SELECT userid,firstname + ' ' + lastname as name FROM [user] ";

        SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
        com.CommandText = str;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                ComboUserData.Add(new User { UserID = (string)sdr["userid"], FirstName = (string)sdr["name"]});
            }

            com.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }


    ObservableCollection<User> _comboUserData;
    public ObservableCollection<User> ComboUserData
    {
        get
        {
            if (_comboUserData == null)
                _comboUserData = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            return _comboUserData;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _comboUserData)
                _comboUserData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ComboUserData");
        }
    }

    User _user;
    public User SelectedUserID
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set
        {
            _user = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUserID");
        }
    }
}
```

This my XAML

```
                <ComboBox x:Name="DDUserId" 
                          Width="140" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" 
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ComboUserData, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserID}">
                </ComboBox>
```

Main Window XAML

```
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="welcome">
        <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Login" Source="/Views/Login.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Register User" Source="/Views/UserView.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Manage Group" Source="/Views/UserGroupView.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="List User" Source="/Views/UserListingView.xaml" />
        </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    </mui:LinkGroup>
```

Comment: Do you not see any items appearing in your combobox ?

Comment: Yes..when the first time my App running it show user data, but when I change page to user page to add new user and then back to user listing page, the new user I just added not appear. The data source did not updating.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on your getter for the ComboUserData property and verified that your underlying collection is up to date each time ?

Comment: @auburg, i dont think so..can you show me how to get it ?

Comment: Basically you need to verify that your view model class is getting the latest user data from the database

Comment: thanks @auburg, can you show me some example please..

Answer (score 0):

To have your data bindings updated automatically:

1. Your `ViewModel` has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. Your bindings' properties `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` and `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` must be set to `true`

Comment: thanks..can you guide me what should I write on NotifyOnSourceUpdate even handler based on my sample code above? I totally have no idea. Noob here :)

Answer (score 0):

1) After adding the second user check if is saving into the database before going to the User List page.

2) If the new user is added into the database then put the debugger on LoadDataUser method and move to UserList page to see if ComboBox is able to fetch the newly added user or not.

Since you are loading the users in a different page so i don't think it would be problem of notification to the combobox, it should load the users as per the connection.

Comment: yes it saved into the database, the problem is when I change page to UserListing the view (combobox) doesnt update automaticaly. Yes, LoadDataUser is executed but only when I change page to UserListing page **for the first time** App starts. When I change page from UserListing page to other page then back to UserListing page, the LoadDataUser is not executed anymore. What did i do wrong ? any suggestion ?

Comment: Ok, it seems like your UserListingViewModel is not getting called for the second time. One things I can suggest this time. 1) Make sure your UserListing Page's datacontext is set to your viewmodel. By the way what is the link you are using to move between the pages? Is there any button on each page to go back or forward to respective pages?

Comment: Thanks for response, my UserListing page already set to UserListingViewModel. I create this app using modernUI which i got from codeplex and for the navigation between pages I use modernUI link . Please see my update (xaml) above..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Found the solution
maybe it's just trick but it works..

I Just follow article in this link
http://blog.cylewitruk.com/2010/10/mvvm-using-a-timer-in-your-viewmodel/[^]

Here is the code :

```
private ShowUser showuser;
private void InvalidateSampleData(object state, EventArgs e)
{
    showuser = new ShowUser();
    Users = showuser.GetUser();
}




public class ShowUser : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> GetUser()
    {
        ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
            "dLondre.Properties.Settings.CSLONDRE"].ConnectionString);

        string str = "";
        str += "SELECT userid,firstname + ' ' + lastname as name FROM [user] ";

        SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
        com.CommandText = str;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                users.Add(new User { UserID = (string)sdr["userid"], FirstName = (string)sdr["name"] });
            }

            com.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return users;
    }

    #region Methods
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

private ObservableCollection<User> _users;
public ObservableCollection<User> Users
{
    get { return _users; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _users)
            _users = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Users");
    }
}

User _user;
public User SelectedUserID
{
    get { return _user; }
    set
    {
        _user = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUserID");
        //MessageBox.Show("Do your Task with " + value.UserID);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help and suggestion to this thread
I really appreciate it..
now I can die in peace..  ;)